# Should class method __iadd__ always preserve the type class?

Tags: python, methods

I have looked for an explicit answer, but the closest result was in the python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__). It says:

> These [augmented arithmetic assignments] methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self).

This *implies* the self (and the type) are unchanged, but is really up to the class developer to determine or should an attempt be make to *always* maintain the type?

I'm aware that **should** is an opinion question. What I'm looking for is better documented evidence on expected result.

Take the class `NumString` below.

```py
class NumString:
    """A class where the number is represented as a string.

    other methods omitted for brevity.
    """
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = str(value)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.value))

    def __add__(self, other):
        if '.' in self.value:
            return float(self) + other
        return int(self) + other

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.value = str(self + other)
        return self
```

Comment: On the `mypy` project, there is a [relevant discussion in this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6225).  Python really does _not_ specify the behavior of what any of these dunder magic methods for operator overloading may achieve, but if you want a good/stable API that users can trust, perhaps the return value should fulfill some correct expectations that satisfy the expected type that the user may expect.

Comment: @metatoaster, it seems that thread is leaning towards `cls.__iadd__() -> cls:`